# how to adb wait-for-device until the home screen shows up?

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I need to unlock my screen using adb, and wait-for-device exits way too early(when the device is booting up), and screen unlock fails. Is there a way to detect that the home screen, so I can fire screen unlock then?

This is the command I am using to unlock screen -

```
adb wait-for-device shell input keyevent 82
```